# Is there is any way to scrape the dynamic content using php or java

Tags: java, php

I need to scrape some details from a website. It loads certain details in Ajax after a button click.  Is it is possible to scrape the details from this [link](http://www.guruji.com/music/3%20idiots/)?

It loads the details when the `+` button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use an ajax callback function and clean the response you receive according to your wishes:

```
    var ajaxurl ='myserver.com/mypage.php';
    var ajaxparams = {
        do:           'get_my_page',
    }

    $.post(ajaxurl, ajaxparams, function(response, status){
        if (status == 'success')
        {
            //handle the response her and clean it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL from which the site loads the dynamic content with Ajax is apparently randomly generated, so you will have to scrape it from the HTML of the original page. It can be found in calls to the Javascript function `getMusicDetails` which is called in the link onclick handlers as follows:

```
<a onclick="getMusicDetails('0','/md?doc=random_doc_id_here&amp;q=3%20idiots','both');..." />
```

There doesn't seem to be any session-specific protection of the content, so once you have the ID, it should simply be a matter of issuing a GET to the following URL: `http://www.guruji.com/md?doc=random_doc_id_here&q=3%20idiots&rindex=0`

(The sample data covers the first plus-link on the page, the other parameters might also vary)